# How to use sklearn LDA coef_ for feature selection

Tags: scikit-learn, selection

I have a set of features Train = [a1, a2, ..., aN], and Train_label = [y1, y2, ..., yN]. I have 3 classes. I applied LDA

```
clf = LDA(store_covariance = True)
clf.fit(Train, Train_label)
```

and tried to get the importance of these features by

```
clf.coef_.
```

The result is a 3XN array. The range of returned values are from around negative 800 to around positive 800. The plot shows the weights of one classclf.coef_[1,:]

[image: weights of one classclf.coef_[1,:]]
What do the negative values mean?

I select the features for each class with the first 3 largest coef_ value to do classification (cross validation and training and test) again.

```
selected_features = [a27, a22, a5, a23, a10, a42]
```

where, a27, a22, a5 are selected 3 features with largest coef for the first class, a27, a23, a10 for the second class, and a27, a10, a42 for the third class.

But the classification accuracy decreased a lot! The results are even worse than a few features I selected before.I tried with 6 selected features with largest coef_ value and results were also bad.

Can any one tell me where is wrong and explain to me what is the correct way to do feature selection using LDA?

Comment: share also your code please

Comment: Hi MMF, code added.